# Free structure diagram (mind-mapping or flowchart) software for high-quality publications

Tags: gratis, open-source

I have done extensive research on trying to find free software that I can use to make publication quality structure diagrams and flowcharts with but have yet to find something suitable.

Tools I currently know about are:

- XMind
- Freeplane
- FreeMind

And then there are a bunch listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_concept-_and_mind-mapping_software).

The problem with all of these are that they either make mind-maps that have quirky stiles that don't look very technical/professional or they don't support PDF or PS or high quality bitmap exporting.

I really like XMind, but the free version export totally rubbish quality bitmaps and no PDF.

What I currently use is LibreOffice Draw, but I have to manually place objects and manually connect them with lines and arrows etc. Thus not a very efficient workflow.

What are the tools that you use? Do you have anything that you can recommend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [Gnome Dia](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Dia/).

This can be looked upon as a cut down, GPL licenced replacement for Visio.  Although it nowhere near the facilities of Visio, it does have the features you ask for and will export in a number of formats.

It is available for Windows, Mac & Linux.